# wordpress get all publish pages permalinks

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I want to get the permalinks of all published pages and export it to an excel file.

**What is the best solution?**

- Should I go to wp-admin panel and copy-paste the permalinks from the on Page editor?
- Can I get the export data using a mysql query?

Comment: Note: I answered the subject in your Question title. You should be more precise in your question, i.e. getting all permalinks AND exporting to an EXCEL file..? Exporting can be a compex thing and also an Excel file is a bit too much to answer in a single question. Please also post any code or approach you tried so far - we don't want to do your work but help you get on the right track...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible but very difficult to do via a SQL query, because WordPress allows you to change your Permalink structure - so the SQL query would need to regard all permalink options to build the correct permalink when the query is executed.

And I guess you are looking for a way that does *not* require you to copy paste links from the admin page ;-)

By far the best and easiest thing to do is write a small script that runs the export for you within WordPress and uses the functions [`get_pages`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages) and [`get_permalink`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink):

```
// Get a list of all published pages from WordPress.
$pages = get_pages( 'post_status=publish' );

// Loop through all pages and fetch the permalink for each page.
foreach ( $pages as $page ) { //fixed this too
  $permalink = get_permalink( $page->ID );
  // Do something with the permalink now...
}
```

Note: This code will only run inside WordPress, i.e. as as Plugin or inside a Theme. Also how to do the excel export is beyond the scope of my answer...

---

Personally I'd create a WordPress plugin (there are many guides out there on how this works, [like this one](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/09/30/how-to-create-a-wordpress-plugin/)).
In the plugin you could simply check for a URL param, and if this param is present then export the data. Additionally I would check if the user that requests the export has admin permissions before exporting the data.

A bit like this:

```
/** 
 * The WordPress plugin header... 
 */

$allowed = false;
$requested = false;

// Check if the current user has admin capabilies.
if ( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) { $allowed = true; }

// Check if the user requested the export.
// i.e. by calling URL http://yoursite.com?export_permalinks=1
if ( 1 == $_GET['export_permalinks'] ) { $requested = true; }

if ( $requested && $allowed ) {
  // 1. Get a list of all published pages from WordPress.
  $pages = get_pages( 'post_status=publish' );

  // 2. Build the export data.
  $export = array();
  foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
    $permalink = get_permalink( $page->ID );
    $export[] = array( $page->ID, $permalink );
  }

   // 3. Export the data (I just var_dump it as example).
   var_dump( $export );

   // We're done, so don't execute anything else.
   exit;
}
```

*Please note that this code should only explain my suggested workflow. It does not use best practices and I don't recommend to use it like this on a live site*

Comment: Thanks but I get this error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'as' (T_AS), expecting ';' in`

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up @Si8 I've fixed the code sample above. Obviously, the loop should be `foreach` and not `for`

Comment: You're welcome! I also updated your first sample code too.